# Show that $\frac{3}{2}=sup\{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{(-1)^n*n}{n+1}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

How to show that $\frac{3}{2}=sup\{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{(-1)^n*n}{n+1}\}$

I have been show that $\frac{3}{2}$ is an upper bound but how can i show is the supremum?

I tried to say that $S$ is the sup, if $S<0$ then its obvious that exist an element x in the set such that $S<x$ but what if $0<S<\frac{3}{2}$ im stuck any hint?

Comment: What about $\frac{7}{6}$? Is it an upper bound? More generally, what can you say about the behaviour of $\frac{2k}{2k + 1} + \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh $\frac{7}{6}$ is not an upper bound for n=4 is bigger, mmm for $\frac{2k}{2k + 1} + \frac{1}{2}$ 3/2 still doing an upper bound

Comment: I wanted you to observe that $\frac{2k}{2k + 1} + \frac{1}{2}$ converges to $\frac{3}{2}$. From here can you conclude something?

Answer (score 1):

You have to find the supremum of $a_n=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{(-1)^n n}{n+1}$. Let's consider some initial terms of the sequence.

$a_0=\frac{1}{2}+0=\frac{1}{2}$
$a_1=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}=0$
$a_2=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{7}{6}>a_0$
$a_3=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{3}{4}=-\frac{1}{4}<a_1$

So I will try to prove that the subsequence of the odd terms is decreasing and that of the even terms is increasing.

$$a_{2n}\leq a_{2n+2}\,\, \forall n\geq 0$$
since $\frac{2n}{(2n+1)}<\frac{(2n+2)}{(2n+3)}$ $\forall n\geq 0$.
$$a_{2n+1}<a_{2n-1} \,\, \forall n\geq 1$$
since $1/2-\frac{(2n+1)}{(2n+2)}<1/2-\frac{(2n-1)}{(2n)}$ $\forall n>0$.
So:
$$\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}=1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}=sup\{a_{2n}\}$$
$$\exists \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n+1}=-1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{-1}{2}=inf\{a_{2n+1}\}$$
Since $a_{2n+1}$ is decreasing then $a_{1}\geq a_{2n+1}$ $\forall n\geq 1$ and so $a_{1}=0=sup\{a_{2n+1}\}=max{a_{2n+1}}$.

Finally since $a_{n}=a_{2n}\cup a_{2n+1}$ then $sup\{a_{n}\}=max\{0,\frac{3}{2}\}=\frac{3}{2}$.